# Translating posts

Tags: feature-request, non-english-speakers, posts, english, translations

I recently edited a post that was in German. I can speak a little German, but used this:

http://translate.reference.com/translate

Using this experience as an example, Am I able to create some useful place, either via this site or Stack Overflow, in the form of a question of wiki to offer users a way to edit their posts for English?

Comment: I hope the OP of the linked question understands English. Back to your question, I don't think SO or Meta SO would be the appropriate place for helping non-English speakers to translate their posts.

Comment: I commented to the OP in both English and German (so both users and OP could understand) that he should translate his text and offered him the link to a translation site. It is irrelevant whether or not he understands English, as I've offered him an avenue to communicating and done so in his language (pls see comment under his question)

Comment: Ok, just saw his comment under the question that he does. It was a "by-the-way" kind of remark though.

Comment: He speaks English well! lol yes, I thought about it, as if, he can't read English, then he wouldn't understand the answers if he couldn't translate them - although the coding language is universal, but the explanations

Comment: You mean a site where SO as a whole (meaning questions and answers) is run through a translation engine? Those already exist...mostly scammy, ad-infested places, but that already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that all of the SE sites' content is Creative Commons-licenced.

You can copy it all (and write some software to keep your copy updated) and then translate<sup>*</sup> and publish to your hearts' content.

Just remember to attribute the copyright correctly according to the relevant CC licence.

** Remember to check the terms and conditions of the translation service!*

Comment: wht do you mean by copy it all?

Comment: @Yve I mean that you can download it all (and legally keep a copy of it around). There is a dump published, described here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/

Comment: yes I have found that.. are you suggesting I create a program for users to use to translate within Stack?

Comment: Well, that is up to you - I just wanted to draw your attention to the fact that the content is CC licenced, so you can build translated sites quite freely without having to worry about any sort of legal action, if you abide to the CC licence, of course.

Comment: Thank you Monolo. Yes that is really good feedback. I usually post questions on Meta that are unpopular! But you answered it for me cheers!

Comment: in response to your edit - pls read my profile on Stack, the last line in the about me bit ! ;) don't worry my browser is magnified

Comment: @Yve thanks for the heads-up. For now, I have left it emphasised, some day there will be a proper way to do footnotes.